# simplify python code with list or dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have the following code:

```
@staticmethod
    def _keep_leads_baldat(leads_aggregated, month, year):
        if month == 1:
            print("proces date - year : " + str(year) + ", month : " + str(month), "baldat : " + str(year - 1) + "03")
            print(PROCESS_DATE + str(year) + MONTH + str(month), BALDAT + str(year - 1) + "03")
            leads_aggregated_final = leads_aggregated.where(substring(col("BALDAT"), 1, 6) == str(year - 1) + "03")
 
        if month == 2:
            print("proces date - year : " + str(year) + ", month : " + str(month), "baldat : " + str(year - 1) + "04")
            print(PROCESS_DATE + str(year) + MONTH + str(month), BALDAT + str(year - 1) + "04")
            leads_aggregated_final = leads_aggregated.where(substring(col("BALDAT"), 1, 6) == str(year - 1) + "04")
 
        if month == 3:
            print("proces date - year : " + str(year) + ", month : " + str(month), "baldat : " + str(year - 1) + "05")
            print(PROCESS_DATE + str(year) + MONTH + str(month), BALDAT + str(year - 1) + "05")
            leads_aggregated_final = leads_aggregated.where(substring(col("BALDAT"), 1, 6) == str(year - 1) + "05")
```

............... .... and so on till month 12. I would like to simplify it, so I do not repeat one block 12 times.

I thought about making list of months, but I am not sure what to do with different strings at the end for every month. Or maybe make dictionary month = {1 : "03", 2 : "04", 3 : "05"........}Any ideas? With example if possible. Thank you.

Comment: Simply `f'{month % 12 + 2:02d}'`…!? The only thing that changes between these variations is that number, which seems to be directly computable from the `month` variable…

Comment: use a list `['00','03','04',...]`, and then `month_list[month]`

Comment: Is the mapping always n+2 (1=>03, 2=> 04, etc...)? Or does it wrap around at the end so `11` becomes `01`, `12` `02`? What about `10`?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: As @tobias_k noticed, using `f"{month+2:02}"` will work for the values 8, 9 & 10 which will become 10, 11, 12 respectively.
It will add 2 to the month, and it will keep only 2 digits - this is specified by `:02` (previous solution would be 011, 012, 013 which is wrong).

```py
@staticmethod
def _keep_leads_baldat(leads_aggregated, month, year):
    print("proces date - year : " + str(year) + ", month : " + str(month), "baldat : " + str(year - 1) + f"{month+2:02}")
    print(PROCESS_DATE + str(year) + MONTH + str(month), BALDAT + str(year - 1) + f"{month+2:02}")
    leads_aggregated_final = leads_aggregated.where(substring(col("BALDAT"), 1, 6) == str(year - 1) + f"{month+2:02}")
```

Comment: Better use something like `f"{month+2:02}"` or it probably won't work for October, November and December.

Comment: Ahh I see. You are right.

Comment: @Rosi If this solves your answer, can you mark it as the correct answer (you click the grey tick-mark next to the voting section)?

Answer (score 0):

```py
@staticmethod
    def _keep_leads_baldat(leads_aggregated, month, year):
        print("proces date - year : " + str(year) + ", month : " + str(month), "baldat : " + str(year - 1) + f"0{month+2}")
        print(PROCESS_DATE + str(year) + MONTH + str(month), BALDAT + str(year - 1) + f"0{month+2}")
        leads_aggregated_final = leads_aggregated.where(substring(col("BALDAT"), 1, 6) == str(year - 1) + f"0{month+2}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a data structure (neither list nor dictionary). You can compute the value of your "03", "04", "05" strings mathematically using `(month+1)%12 + 1` and just have one code block for the whole year :

The computation will provide the appropriate values:

```
for month in range(1,13):
    print(month, (month+1)%12 + 1)

1 3
2 4
3 5
4 6
5 7
6 8
7 9
8 10
9 11
10 12
11 1
12 2
```

And your code can be simplified to:

```
def _keep_leads_baldat(leads_aggregated, month, year):
    prevYM = str(year - 1) + str((month+1)%12 + 1).rjust(2,"0")
    print("proces date - year : " + str(year) + ", month : " + str(month), "baldat : " + prevYM)
    print(PROCESS_DATE + str(year) + MONTH + str(month), BALDAT + prevYM)
    leads_aggregated_final = leads_aggregated.where(substring(col("BALDAT"), 1, 6) == prevYM)
```